# Post value and retrieve it in Code Behind using Request

Tags: asp.net, request, postback, multilingual

I'm writing a multilingual web application using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eX5um3zSxjI) video as a tutorial:

In this video the web's language change is carried out with a DropDown Menu that posts the desired culture ID (en-UK, es, fr...). That value is retrieved in code behind and used to set the correct parameter like this.

```
    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        String language = Request.Form["DropDownList"];
        if ((language != null) && (language != ""))
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
        }
    }
```

I don't like the idea of the DropDownList and want the user to click on a flag to switch to that language. I achieved that with a hyperlink:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkSpanish" runat="server" NavigateUrl="Tool.aspx?id=es"><img src="img/es.png"></asp:HyperLink>
```

The posted QueryParameter is then retrieved in the InitializeCulture method with:

```
String language = Request.QueryString["id"];
```

That works fine, but whenever you click on the HyperLink the page is reloaded from scratch, while my idea was to translate everything displayed so far in the chosen language. I'm a complete autodidact and wonder how to achieve that same mechanism (posting & retrieving it's value with Request.Form["ControlID"]) but using a LinkButton and a Click event...

...or any other suggestion. Thanks, Martin
-----

What I forgot to point out is that I'm using references to a resource file in my markup that place the correct text according to the chosen Culture ID:

```
HeaderText="<%$ Resources: Resource, Grid01Documentation %>"
```

So changing the language affects all GridView Headers, Button, etc...

Comment: Are you familiar with the `LinkButton` control? You could use a series of `<asp:LinkButton ... />` controls. Set the `CommandName` attribute to something like "SetLanguage", `CommandArgument` to the culture string, attach a single `Click` event handler to all instances. In the `Click` event handler, retrieve the `CommandName` and `CommandArgument` properties and set the culture properties of the thread just like you are now. Then, use some CSS to style the control how you'd like it to look.

Comment: If you use a `LinkButton` then you can give it a `CommandArgument` specifying the culture ID and retrieve that value in the click handler.  But it's not really clear what you mean by "reloaded from scratch" vs. "translate everything displayed so far" and how that relates to using a `LinkButton`.  Are you just asking how to use a `LinkButton` (there are examples on MSDN, no?), or are you asking something else?

Comment: I tried what you said and I can actually change the culture properties in the LinkButton Event Handler. BUT what doesn't work is that all the Text tags in my mark up  (Text="<%$ Resources: Resource, Grid01Volume %>") do retrieve the correct Text from the resource file, according to the chosen language. That worked first, when using the override InitializeCulture() method.

Comment: @David reload from scratch in my case means that all tables, detail views that the user has open, selected,.. will disappear, as the pages is actually reloaded.